# Creating Virtual Keyboard Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First thing: I'm new. So I'm trying to build a virtual keyboard in Unity. I'm starting with one key, and one InputField.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class KeyboardScript : MonoBehaviour {
InputField iField;

public void onClick() {
string key = "k";
iField.text(key);
}
}
```

Here's how I interpret the code I wrote:
1) using UnityEngine.UI allows me to reference UI GameObjects.

2) InputField is the name of my input field and I let the computer know it is an iField.

3)This code is a component of my button which is called K, and so onClick() means when button K is clicked.

4) Let string called key equal letter k.

5) Let the text inside InputField equal k.

**My error says "The member 'UnityEngine.UI.InputField.Text' cannot be used as method or delegate.**

I appreciate any advice. I have looked at the Unity manuals and other things, I just need a human's help because I don't know what I'm looking at.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your virtual keyboard is going to be made up of `GameObjects` which represent keys?

In which case, each of your `GameObjects` (your keys) needs to have a `Collider` on it, in order for mouse clicks to register.

Once you have a `Collider` on each key of your virtual keyboard, you can register the clicks by using Unity's built in function `OnMouseDown()`.

So you may have a `GameObject` with a `Collider` on it, which is called "K".

You can then change your Input Field based on what your Key `GameObject` is called when you click on it, something like:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    yourInputField.text = gameObject.name;
}
```

EDIT:
I've never really worked with an `InputField` in Unity, so I don't know if setting the text like this will work, however this is probably the best way to register clicks on a `GameObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set text in the way you do.
This one is correct

```
// Input field will display only your key
iField.text = key;

// Input field will display current text + your key
iField.text += key;
```